# Transforming integers in a string to words in a list comprehension

Tags: python, string, text

I have a string that contains integers and I am trying to work out how to transform them into words (i.e. 100 into one hundred). I am using the `inflect` package with success with individual cases, however I am struggling to find the correct solution that enables me to keep the sentence as-is, aside from the integer transformation.

This is what I have at present:

```
mysent = ['this','is','1','of','my','sentences']
```

and this is what i want to end up with:

```
mysent = ['this','is','one','of','my','sentences']
```

So far I have tried the following, which is removing all words except the integer.

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

mysent = [p.number_to_words(token) for token in mysent if token.isdigit() is True]
```

I have also tried the below which I thought might solve the problem, but produces a syntax error:

```
mysent = [p.number_to_words(token) for token in mysent if token.isdigit() is True else token for token in mysent]
```

Comment: Could you also post the error message here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Python's [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator):

```
result = [p.number_to_words(token) if token.isdigit() else token for token in mysent]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['this', 'is', 'one', 'of', 'my', 'sentences']
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write `if` after `for` in a list comprehension, you are filtering the list by excluding those elements for which the condition is false. This means you exclude the non-numeric words, which isn't what you want.

Instead, you should write `p.number_to_words(token) if token.isdigit() else token` to include either the conversion, or the original token, into the resulting list, depending on the condition. The full comprehension looks like this:

```py
mysent = [p.number_to_words(token) if token.isdigit() else token for token in mysent]
```

By the way, assuming `token.isdigit()` returns either `True` or `False`, it is redundant to write `is True`.

Comment: Great thanks. I guessed that may have been the problem but wasn't quite sure how to correct it. Thanks for the info re: 'is true' statement as well.